# Getting IE to replace a regex with the literal string "$0"

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm replacing a bunch of values in a regex with dollar amounts.  The problem is that in IE, if I attempt to replace with an amount of `$0` (or, theoretically, `$1`--`$9`), the replace never occurs since the it's trying to replace a non-existant group:

```
'foo'.replace(/f/g, '$0');
```

I want the result of that replacement to be "$0oo", which it is in Chrome & FF, but not IE9 (haven't tried other versions of IE).

Chrome & FF have an "issue" with the following, in that I can't figure out how to replace with a literal `$1`:

```
'foo'.replace(/(f)/g, '$1')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write `"$$0"` to escape the `$` sign.

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome and Firefox you can workaround this limitation by using a function as the second argument of the replace function:

```
'foo'.replace(/(f)/g, function(){return '$1';}); // => $1oo
```

My own testing shows that IE8 is consistent with the other browsers on this issue.

Comment: thanks :)  I'll accept in a bit, but would prefer a solution that involves somehow escaping the `$` as opposed to the function call overhead

Comment: How much overhead are we thinking this is?

Answer (score 3):

The Problem:

```
'My Bank balance is {0} '.replace(/\{0\}/,'$0.22')
 results: "My Bank balance is {0}.22 " 
 This is not what we want
```

The solution:

```
'My Bank balance is {0} '.replace(/\{0\}/,'$$0.22')
results: "My Bank balance is $0.22 " 
'My Bank balance is {0} '.replace(/\{0\}/,"$0.22".replace(/\$/,'$$$$'))
result: "My Bank balance is $0.22 "
```

Explanation: I am trying to find '$' and replace by '$$'. To match '$' you have to escape it by '\$' and to replace '$$$$' you have to put four '$' as RegEx escape '$' for '$$'. Fun!!

Answer (score 1):

@SLaks that should be more like: write "$$" for literal "$".

@cwolves getting a literal instead of a 'special' character (like "$" here) usually involves either doubling it or prefixing it with "\".

Comment: normal escape sign, "\" wasn't working, and ___nothing___ else in JS is escaped by doubling it, so it never occurred to me :)